# Showing UIWebView over tableView in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uitableview

I added a rightBarButton and I'd like to have that button hide the TableView and show my UIWebView, but I am not seeing the web view.

UITableViewController

viewDidLoad:

```
    mWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 380)];
    [mWebView loadHTMLString:@"<html><body>Testing</body></html>" baseURL:nil];
    mWebView.hidden=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:mWebView];
```

onButton:

```
    mWebView.hidden = NO;
    self.tableView.hidden=YES;
```

The tableView disappears, but all I get is a white screen instead of the expected 'Testing'

Comment: Did you add tableView as subview ?  if not do like below [self.view addSubview:tableView ];

Comment: This is a UITableViewController subclass, so tableView is already setup. Is my alloc/init or addSubview call wrong??

Comment: I can't even find an example of a webview being added programmatically on the web. Or any view being added to a UITableViewController like I'm attempting.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add `[mWebView setNeedsDisplay]` and possibly `[self.tableView setNeedsDisplay]`.

Comment: Added to my button handler, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[webview setBackGroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];`

and `[webview setOpaque: NO];`

Comment: This isn't what I want, but setting the background color doesn't do anything so it looks like the webview wasn't added when i did addsubview?? Unless the init is bad..